# GNOME Shell: Maximize/switch apps by scrolling in taskbar

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, scrolling, taskbar, ubuntu-dock

Just moved from Unity to GNOME Shell with the update to Ubuntu 17.10. In Unity I could maximize apps by placing my cursor on the app in the taskbar and scrolling.

In GNOME this doesn't work. Is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Ubuntu 17.10 release, Ubuntu has moved away from Unity to GNOME. There's no going back to Unity, unfortunately.

There are a lot of differences between the new Ubuntu dock and the older Unity dock. However, with a GNOME shell extension called [Dash to Dock](https://micheleg.github.io/dash-to-dock/), you can get very close to the Unity experience.

Go to the [Dash to Dock GNOME Shell Extensions installer page](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/).

From the installer page:

> To control GNOME Shell extensions using this site you must install
>   GNOME Shell integration that consists of two parts: browser extension
>   and native host messaging application.

Instructions for both of them are mentioned there. In a nutshell,

1. One click Chrome extension install
2. Native app using `sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell`

After both are installed, Dash To Dock extension can then be directly installed, enabled, and opened from the same browser window.

Using this, I was able to make my dock look like this:
[Customized Ubuntu GNOME dock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmcpr.png)

Here's a screenshot of the setting that will enable the "scrolling" feature:
[Dash to Dock scroll action behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3LVY.png)

Pretty cool.

Additionally, download [Ubuntu GNOME Tweak Tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/) for an array of customisation.

Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to install another dock extension, the cycle windows feature can be enabled for the Ubuntu dock from command line:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock scroll-action 'cycle-windows'
```

Comment: You are my hero of the day! I've been looking for a way to get this functionality back for weeks, but for some reason I haven't been able to find any mention of this anywhere until today. The scroll-to-cycle-windows function was one I used heavily in Unity for things like a bunch of maximized terminals or two or three IDE instances for different projects.

Comment: worked perfectly on ubuntu 18.10. Thanks for this gem

Comment: On ubuntu 22.04 it works out of the box.